# Importing t5-base from T5Tokenizer fails

Tags: python, nlp

I have been trying to load pretrained t5-base from the T5Tokenizer transformer in python. However it is not working after repeated attempts.
[The Output shows "None"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzLnt.png)

```
!pip install sentencepiece==0.1.91
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-base")
print(tokenizer)
```

The output of the above code is: None

A [GitHub page](https://github.com/abhimishra91/transformers-tutorials/issues/19) says that version 0.1.91 of the sentencepiece library is required for t5-base. However, it is still not working as you can see in the above image.

What can be done in this case?

Comment: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/9093#issuecomment-753474111

Comment: Please post text instead of images - see [ask].

Comment: @JayMody Thank you for replying. I tried the 0.1.94 version as well, but it is still not working.

Comment: It works fine for me no errors

Comment: Version `0.1.94` worked for me